# Add user attribute in IdToken AWS cognito Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

Consider I Have Following Attribute In user pool

- username
- first-name
- last-name
- location

How to add All **attribute** in **IdToken** after successful authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the ID Token specification, the response claim doesn't have these attribute values (user name, first & last name, location etc.).

However, as part of the [standard claim](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims), you can get these attributes using [USERINFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html) endpoint.

[ID Token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)